# How do you find the incidental equation when using the Frobenius method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, differential-forms, formal-power-series, frobenius-method

If I'm not mistaken, the Frobenius Series is given by
$$
y = a_{0}x^{r} + a_{1}x^{r+1} + a_{2}x^{r+2} + \dots + a_{n}x^{r+n} + \dots
$$
and so we also have
$$
y' = ra_{0}x^{r-1} + (r+1)a_{1}x^{r} + (r+2)a_{2}x^{r+1} + \dots + (r+n)a_{n}x^{r+n-1} + \dots
$$
and
$$
y'' =  r(r-1)a_{0}x^{r-2} + (r+1)ra_{1}x^{r-1} + (r+2)(r+1)a_{2}x^{r} + \dots + (r+n)(r+n-1)a_{n}x^{r+n-2} + \dots
$$

To then use the Frobenius method to solve an  ODE of the form $p(x) y'' + q(x) y' + r(x) y = 0$, we must substitute in the values of $y'', y', y$ given by the Frobenius series, and simplify the resulting equation.

What is the next step in this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify: the Frobenius method is a method to find a solution of the ODE *around a regular singular point* of that ODE. For simplicity, assume that $x = 0$ is a regular singular point: that means that we can write
\begin{align}
 p(x) &= x^2 P(x),\\
 q(x) &= x Q(x),
\end{align}
where $P$, $Q$ and $r$ are *not* zero when $x=0$. The ODE can then be rewritten as
\begin{equation}
 y'' + \frac{1}{x} \frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}\,y' + \frac{1}{x^2} \frac{r(x)}{P(x)} y= 0.
\end{equation}
If you now substitute the series expansions you found (where you already implicitly assumed that indeed $x=0$ was the regular singular point you're expanding about), you obtain
\begin{equation}
 [r(r-1) + \frac{Q(x)}{P(x)} r + \frac{r(x)}{P(x)}]a_0 x^r + \sum_{n=1}^\infty [(n+r-1)(n+r) + \frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}(n+r) + \frac{r(x)}{P(x)}]a_n x^{n+r} = 0.
\end{equation}
This equation should hold for all $x$, so in particular for the regular singular point $x=0$. This gives you the so-called *indicial equation*
\begin{equation}
 r(r-1) + \frac{Q(0)}{P(0)} r+ \frac{r(0)}{P(0)} = 0.
\end{equation}
This equation is a quadratic equation for $r$: its solutions give you two $r$-values for which the ODE can be solved using this series assumption. If the difference of those two roots of the indicial equation is *not* an integer, you're basically done; if the difference *is* equal to an integer, you have to adjust the series Ansatz a bit, see [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method)  for more information.

Comment: Excellent answer.